# HIbernate: Detach parent and all children

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have a object tree like this:

Foo->(Many)Bar->Baz

I want to make them all transient but calling detach on Foo only detaches Foo. I also do not want to clear the session because there may be other things in the session that need to remain.

Is there a way to do with without spidering all over the tree? Or is there a way in the original query that loaded Foo to say that none of the objects returned should be attached?

Answer (score 0):

Hiberante's detach method does just this:

```
public void detach(Object entity) {
    try {
        getSession().evict( entity );
    }
    catch ( HibernateException he ) {
        throw convert( he );
    }
}
```

Its more or less like: you already have the object, so, lets just evict it from the session letting it detached. What you could do is cascade `EVICT` on this property, so when `Foo` is evicted `Bar` is evicted too and so does `Baz`. In order to avoid `LazyInitializationException` you need to warranty they are all loaded (maybe `FetchType EAGER`?)

---

For 3.5 you have the CascadeType `DETACH`, that could be used for this purpose: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html